# Is there a Passenger compatible implementation of taps for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, deployment, database-replication

Does anybody know of a gem that provides [taps](http://github.com/ricardochimal/taps)-like functionality, that is compatible with [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) (mod_rails)?

When I try to use taps on a Ruby EE/Passenger setup, I receive the error:

```
`detect_rack_handler': Server handler (thin,mongrel,webrick) not found. (RuntimeError)
```

Although it's not specifically stated in the readme, I am assuming this means that taps is only compatible with Thin/Mongrel/Webrick.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to easily push my PostgreSQL database to development to production.

Answer (score 0):

You could tunnel [Postgres over SSH](http://pgedit.com/tip/postgresql/ssh_tunneling), that's very secure and you could use whatever backup / restore tools you currently have on your development machine.